# How to apply single and two qubit gates to 2 qubits multiple times?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Let's say we have the following quantum circuit:

[image]

Let's say we input the state $|00\rangle$ . Both of the $H$ gates produce the output $1/\sqrt{2}$, but which one of the following $2$ vectors is the input of $\operatorname{CNOT}$ gate:
$1: [1/\sqrt{2}, \ 1/\sqrt{2}, \ 1/\sqrt{2}, \ 1/\sqrt{2}]$ or
$2: [1/2, \ 1/2, \ 1/2, \ 1/2]$?
Also, after applying a $2$ qubit gate (in this case $\operatorname{CNOT}$) how do we find out what to input in the following single qubit gates (in this case two $H$ gates)?
Note that I gave this example for simplicity, a general answer will also be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1** (application of two hadamard gates):

$$|0\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B \to \left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_A\otimes\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_B$$

This is equivalent to the state vector: $\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\\1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}$, which will act as the input for your CNOT gate.

**Step 2**: (application of CNOT)

Let's remind ourselves what the CNOT gate does:

[image]

So clearly, 
$$\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_A\otimes\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_B = \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle)$$ $$\to \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |11\rangle + |10\rangle) = \left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_A\otimes\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_B$$

**Step 3:** (re-application of two Hadamard gates)

$$\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_A\otimes\left(\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)_B \to |0\rangle_A \otimes |0\rangle_B$$

Here, we used that fact that the Hadamard gate maps the state $\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ to the state $|0\rangle$, for each qubit. You basically need to input the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$ into the two Hadamard gates at the end. Find the state transformation on each qubit. From there you can construct the state vector for the final 2-qubit state. The final answer will be $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Clearly, we end up with the same 2-qubit state which we started with.

**Exercise**: Carry out steps $2$ and $3$ using the matrix notation. Also, check [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2271/26) related answer.